# C++ template t is not valid template type

Tags: c++, templates

My .h file:

```
template <typename T>
class UpdateUtils
{
public:
typedef struct {
    QList<T> file;
} TPath;

static TPath *getIdealPath(QList<TPath *> &paths);
};
```

My .cpp file:

```
template <typename T>
TPath *UpdateUtils<T>::getIdealPath(QList<TPath *> &paths) {
   return 0;
}
```

This produces errors in cpp file:

> ```
> error: C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
> error: C2065: 'T' : undeclared identifier
> error: C2923: 'UpdateUtils' : 'T' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'
> ```

If I replace `TPath *` return type with e.g. `int`, it works. Can you please advise?

Comment: [OT]: Once you solve the problem with return type, you should put the definition in the header file, otherwise the linker will complain

Comment: Drop the C habit of typedeffing structs – `struct TPath {...};` is good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TPath` is a nested class defined inside `UpdateUtils`, you should qualify it and use `typename` keyword. e.g.

```
template <typename T>
typename UpdateUtils<T>::TPath *UpdateUtils<T>::getIdealPath(QList<TPath *> &paths)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or apply [trailing return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) as @PiotrSkotnicki suggested:

```
template <typename T>
auto UpdateUtils<T>::getIdealPath(QList<TPath *> &paths) -> TPath *
^^^^                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note that for member function definition out of class definition, names used in parameter-list and trailing-return-type will be looked up in the class scope, so you don't need to qualify them (it's fine to qualify them though). This doesn't apply for return-type. [[basic.scope.class]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.class#4)

> The potential scope of a declaration that extends to or past the end of a class definition also extends to the regions defined by its member definitions, even if the members are defined lexically outside the class (this includes static data member definitions, nested class definitions, and member function definitions, including the member function body and any portion of the declarator part of such definitions which follows the declarator-id, including a parameter-declaration-clause and any default arguments).

Comment: Or put the name as a trailing return type